# How to force HTTPS and WWW

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I found few very similar topics but none of solution worked for in my situation. How can i both force using of https:// and www through the .htaccess file:

My current code is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

It's important to preserve function that's on the last line for general functioning of the URLs.

Comment: While this won't fix your immediate problem, you should also check out HSTS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Comment: Your htaccess doesn't show any rule to enforce `https` or `www`. Can you add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force HTTPs and WWW use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before you test this.